# Create CommandQueue and Command Allocator using IID_PPV_ARGS

Tags: c++, com, directx-12

I am learning how to create CommandQueue, Command Allocator, and CommandList in DirectX 12.

However, a question arose in the process of creating each with the Create function.

The following is the code from the major.

```
ComPtr<ID3D12CommandQueue> mCommandQueue;
ComPtr<ID3D12CommandAllocator> mDirectCmdListAlloc;
ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList> mCommandList;

ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc,IID_PPV_ARGS(&mCommandQueue)));

ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommandAllocator(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT,IID_PPV_ARGS(&mDirectCmdListAlloc.GetAddressof())));
```

If you look at this code, `IID_PPV_ARGS` and `ComPtr` pointer is used to create the CommandQueue.

However, when creating a CommandAllocator, `IID_PPV_ARGS` and `ComPtr`'s `GetAddressof()` are used.

I don't understand why these two are different.

I know that if I put `&ComPtr` in `IID_PPV_ARGS`, it is converted to COM ID and `void**` using `__uuidof` and `IID_PPV_ARGS_Helper`.

What does it mean to put `ComPtr.getAddressOf()` instead of `&ComPtr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IID_PPV_ARGS()` expects the address of an interface pointer variable.  Both `ComPtr::operator&` and `ComPtr::GetAddressOf()` return such an address - the address of the internal `ComPtr::ptr_` data member.  The only difference between them is that `ComPtr::operator&` calls `Release()` on the current interface if it is not null, whereas `ComPtr::GetAddressOf()` does not (use `ComPtr::ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()` for that).

However, that said, I would not expect `IID_PPV_ARGS(&mDirectCmdListAlloc.GetAddressof())` to compile, for two reasons:

- `ComPtr::GetAddressOf()` returns a temporary variable, and C++ does not allow taking the address of a temporary.
- even if you could, `ComPtr::GetAddressOf()` returns a `T**` pointer, so taking its address would yield a `T***` pointer, which is not what `IID_PPV_ARGS()` wants.  It should be `IID_PPV_ARGS(mDirectCmdListAlloc.GetAddressof())` instead, ie drop the `&`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand. '&mDirectCmdListAlloc.GetAddressof()' is 
typo, 'mDirectCmdListAlloc.GetAddressof()' is right

Comment: Obtaining an interface to COM pointers with either `IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_COM_Object)` or `IID_PPV_ARGS(m_COM_Object.GetAddressOf())` is most likely due to author preference and I've seen both styles occur in equal proportion across all the DirectX 12 code I've read. I prefer the latter style because it makes your intention explicit. If both styles are found to occur within the same author's code, it's most likely a sign of inattentive coding and poor practice. I was also confused by the indiscriminate use of both styles while a novice to DirectX 12 and COM pointers.